# Cloudera Exam: HDFS Question on DataNodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am learning for a Cloudera certificate and I do not comprehend the following scenario regarding HDFS and Data Nodes.

The question is as follows: You need to move a file titled "weblogs" into HDFS. When you try to copy the file, you can’t. You know you have ample space on your DataNodes. Which action should you take to relieve this situation and store more files in HDFS?

1. Increase the block size on all current files in HDFS.
2. Increase the block size on your remaining files.
3. Decrease the block size on your remaining files.
4. Increase the amount of memory for the NameNode.
5. Increase the number of disks (or sizes) for the NameNode.

The right answer is 3. "Decrease the block size on your remaining files."

Why is that so? I would argue with, if the block size is decreased, then more metadata needs to be stored in total.

I searched through the internet, but could not found an answer on this scenario.

Comment: Question didn't give any detail about the Namenode, or how much free space per datanode is available. If one datanode only has 64M of space, and you've got 128M blocksize, then yes, smaller blocks.... But it could just be there's a network problem with the namenode/datanodes, causing any file not to be uploaded, so these choices just don't make sense. Numbers 4 and 5 would also be valid options